# wso2 apim docker - http://host-ip:9443/publisher is downloading a binary file instead of showing a login page

Tags: docker, wso2

I am following https://wso2.com/api-management/install/docker/get-started/ this guide for wso2-apim setup but i cannot see any webpage on these url

```
- Publisher  http://localhost:9443/publisher
- Store  http://localhost:9443/store
- Admin console  http://localhost:9443/admin
- Carbon console  http://localhost:9443/carbon
```

instead on going to these url it downloads a binary file.

docker run -it -p 8280:8280 -p 8243:8243 -p 9443:9443 --name api-manager wso2/wso2am:2.6.0

Comment: there should be `HTTPS` instead of `http`: https://localhost:9443/publisher

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned , all the urls are wrong the correct ones are:

```
Publisher - https://localhost:9443/publisher 
Store - https://localhost:9443/store 
Admin console - https://localhost:9443/admin 
Carbon console - https://localhost:9443/carbon
```

Anyway I can't download a "binary" when I reach the url http://localhost:9443/publisher

I used curl command and get this:

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:9443/publisher                                                                                                                                                                                  
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9443 (#0)
> GET /publisher HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9443
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
P%
```

Could you add more information. What browser did you used ?

Comment: isn't curl localhost:9443/publisher supposed to give html contents ?                                  
    `curl http://localhost:9443/publisher`     -------    output -------
    > P                                                                                                                    
    @miguel

Comment: You get a binary encrypted html page. To decode it you should indicate to curl to use https protocol.